# XWin via Cygwin asks password every time I change keyboard layout

Tags: linux, cygwin, xdmcp

I use Cygwin/X for using of XWin. But every time I wand to change keyboard layout I get prompt window with assking for my password.

In Details->Action it is org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data

XWin is launche with next command line.
run XWin :1 -query %REMOTE_HOST% -clipboard -nodecoration -lesspointer

How to disable this password asking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround.

It was polkit deamon, which ask password every time I switch layout. I've just killed it and kept happy.

Next issue - disable polkit at startup or modify policy, but it is another topic.